# request.getParameter() continues to return null value

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I am having an issue where request.getParameter() continues to return null value. However, instead of this function, if i pass a manual value, that gets updated correctly. Below is my code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="shopper" class="shopping.User" scope="session"/>

    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="Login">
        <h3> Use the form below to login to our site </h3>
        Enter Username:<input type="text" name="uname"/>
        <br/>

        <jsp:setProperty name="shopper" property="name" value="<%= request.getParameter("uname") %>"/>
        Enter Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"/>
        <br/>
        <!--<input type="submit" value="Login-->
    </form>
```

I am calling this value from another file as follows:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="shopper" class="shopping.User" scope="session"/>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Conf Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>INFORMATION</h1>
        <h2> Your name is: <%= shopper.getName() %></h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So basically shopper.getName only returns a non-null value when I provide a manual value in the setProperty line instead of the request.getParameter function. There were similar posts but I could not get much help from those.

Comment: Use `Tamper data` plugin for Firefox in order to see that the value is indeed sent.

Comment: what header_name should I be checking with Tamper data plugin?

Comment: Just turn the plugin on and submit the form - you'll see the parameters on the lower left side of the panel.

Comment: I see multiple headers in lower left side but none that would point towards a username value

Comment: Which means that this value is not sent - now try to figure out why!